# How to inject audio in call stream with APQ8064 Snapdragon

Tags: android, frameworks, call, audio-streaming, alsa

As per my project I need to enable the call recording. I enabled it. I created custom ROM,applied CAF based changes to it and it is working fine now. I can record all calls from both sides.

The next requirement is to insert a beep in the call stream so that other party will come to know that the call is getting recorded. I searched a lot for this and come to know that there are no direct API's available in android. This is hardware and device driver level work. But no one explained how to implement this.

Please refer me somewhere to solve this. Thanks in advance.